# Calling a Google App Script from PHP?

Tags: php, google-apps-script

Is there a way to call a Google App Script with some parameters (a json array for example) from a PHP script?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes publish script to run as owner and anonymous access.
Implement contentService from doGet.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me some more details? I am completely new to Google App Script. Thanks!

Comment: The part specific about apps script is contentService. See official samples that return json.